# Spring boot application file layering

Tags: spring-boot

I have 3 files as below:

```
1. application.yml with some other configurations

2. application-default.yml with contents
   apisigning:
     client:
      sharedKey: 'some xyz'
      secretKey: 'some xyz'
      proxyHost: 127.0.0.1
      port: 9480

3. application-cloud.yml with contents
   apisigning:
     client:
      sharedKey: 'some xyz'
      secretKey: 'some xyz'
```

So when I run the application with default profile I want to use proxy host and port values from the application-default.yml file. But once its deployed in cloud it shouldn't be configuring the proxy host and port values ideally. The issue I am facing is that in cloud env its somehow getting the values for that proxyHost and port. I want to know what is going wrong here? How the layering of yml file is done based on profiles in this case.

Comment: How are you starting the application/how are the profiles getting set

Comment: Yes, the active profile is being passed in the command line arguments

Answer (score -1):

from Spring Boot Reference

24.4 Profile-specific Properties
In addition to application.properties files, profile-specific properties can also be defined by using the following naming convention: application-{profile}.properties. The Environment has a set of default profiles (by default, [default]) that are used if no active profiles are set. In other words, if no profiles are explicitly activated, then properties from application-default.properties are loaded.

Profile-specific properties are loaded from the same locations as standard application.properties, with profile-specific files always overriding the non-specific ones, whether or not the profile-specific files are inside or outside your packaged jar.

If several profiles are specified, a last-wins strategy applies. For example, profiles specified by the spring.profiles.active property are added after those configured through the SpringApplication API and therefore take precedence.

[Note]
If you have specified any files in spring.config.location, profile-specific variants of those files are not considered. Use directories in spring.config.location if you want to also use profile-specific properties.

found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23190644)

Comment: i edited the answer with the essential parts from the spring boot reference

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for the behavior of application in this case. I understand that cloud profile will take preference first but why is it picking the values from default profile as well?

Comment: Did you have something like that: -Dspring.profiles.active=cloud,default in your jvm arguments?The hierarchy which properties are first taken you can see in the spring boot reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html. Perhaps you defined the profile spefic properties somewhere else in your code or external configuration?